# Microsoft Graph API Outlook Inbox filter sender/emailAddress/address does not return expected response

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

When I am trying to filter emails in my inbox using the following Python code snippet,

```
sender_email = 'test@test.de'
filter_expression = f"sender/emailAddress/address eq '{sender_email}'"
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_principal_name}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter={filter_expression}&top=1000"
```

I receive the following empty response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('abc%40test.de')/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    "value": []
}
```

But if I read all mails without filtering, I receive the correct result:

```
...
    "subject": "Scanned images", 
...
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Test User",
            "address": "test@test.de"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Test User",
            "address": "test@test.de"
        }
    },
...
```

Interestingly if I use a filter for the subject, I receive the correct result email

```
filter_expression = f"startswith(subject, 'Scanned')"
```

Here is the code I use for sending the request

```
def graph_get(url, token):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.json()

response = graph_get(url, token)
```

What am I doing wrong with my sender/emailAddress/address filter? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share a code how do you send a request? For now, I can't reproduce the issue , filtering by sender/emailAddress/address works fine

Comment: I have just added the request snippet

Comment: Same code working fine in my case with `sender/emailAddress/address` filter like [this](https://i.imgur.com/21ztUGL.png)

Comment: Could you include how you generated the token with what authentication flow? client credentials or any delegated flows?

Comment: I have added a snippet how I get the token. By the way, the filter worked for other emails with the same email address before. I only recognized some leftover emails when I was trying to move all of mails with the same sender to a specific folder.

Comment: Could you try modifying filter to this: `filter_expression = f"startsWith(from/emailAddress/address,'{sender_email}')"`

Comment: I just figured out, that all leftover emails do have in common, that my email address (which is the owner's address of the inbox) is not in toRecipients, ccRecipients or bccRecipients.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255744/discussion-between-sridevi-and-andreas).

Comment: by using `filter_expression = f"startsWith(from/emailAddress/address,'{sender_email}')"` the filtering works properly

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, filtering `sender/emailAddress/address` with **eq** operator might not work.  As an alternative, you can filter it with **startsWith** operator by modifying your code like this:

```py
filter_expression = f"startsWith(from/emailAddress/address,'{sender_email}')"
```

I registered one Azure AD application and granted `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below python code by modifying the **filter** expression and including above token, I got the results successfully as below:

```py
import requests

sender_email = 'user@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
filter_expression = f"startsWith(from/emailAddress/address,'{sender_email}')"
user_principal_name = 'sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
token = 'paste_token_here'

url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_principal_name}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter={filter_expression}&top=1000"

def graph_get(url, token):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())

response = graph_get(url, token)
```

**Response:**

[image]